# React Native: Record audio in wav file when user click start button and AUTO stop recording when user stop speaking (silent)

Tags: react-native

I want to create voice chat app in react-native like google assistant.

My query is that i want to record audio when user start speaking on button click, and AUTO stop recording when user stop speaking (silent).

I have tried below node packages, but not succeed:
react-native-voice
react-native-audio
react-native-audio-record

Please let me know soon if you have any solution.

Thanks in advance.